# Can't submit form using .closest()

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble to submit a form using .closest() method.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="avatar">
    <form method="POST" action="out" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="9">
        <img src="img/avatars/698dc19d489c4e4db73e28a713eab07b.jpg" class="img-rounded">
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$(".avatar").bind('click',function(){
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
})
```

If I use ID instead of CLASS, it works.

Thanks.

Comment: @MohammadAdil the parent

Comment: Your form is a child of avatar, so you want `find` or `children`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But why it doesn't work using .closest()?

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano `closest()` goes the wrong way through the DOM (searches through the *ancestors*). As noted: you want `find()` (searches through the *descendants*).

Comment: Use `.on()` instead of `.bind()`. From doc: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Answer (score 1):

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) traverses the ancestors, the your form is a child.  Try using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to locate the form.

Answer (score 1):

Use `children` method and you are done

```
$(".avatar").bind('click',function(){
    $(this).children("form").submit();
})
```